# Fancybox 1.3.4 automatically close

Tags: jquery, dynamic, fancybox

I have a dynamically filled Fancybox that is used for address standardization. If no addresses are returned, I want to cancel the Fancybox call automatically. I have tried both of the following with no success:

```
$.fancybox.close();
parent.$.fancybox.close();
window.parent.$.fancybox.close();
$.fancybox.cancel();
```

This is the call I am doing to bring the page up:

```
$.fancybox({
                'autoDimensions': true,
                'autoScale': false,
                'centerOnScroll': false,
                'scrolling': 'no',
                'enableEscapeButton': false,
                'hideOnOverlayClick': true,
                'href': 'url for page',
                'showCloseButton': false,
                'onStart': function() {
                    $.fancybox.showActivity();
                     },
                'type': 'inline'//had issues with iframe
            });
```

The JSP that is loaded into the fancybox window will show the loading activity, but if the server returns null, it will not fully close the fancybox. So far I can get the fancybox to close everything except for the overlay and the content divs. Below is what is being used to call the automatic close:

```
function closeDynamic() { 
    alert("2222");
    $.fancybox.cancel();
}
```

Then calling the closeDynamic function at the bottom of the page.

Comment: My guess? your loaded file (JSP) is triggering a js error that stops fancybox from closing properly. On the other hand, bear in mind that `inline` content refers to content existing (eventually hidden) in the document.

Comment: @JFK thanks for the advice. There was a problem in a JSTL that was causing the issue. I also switched to iframe to save any future issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is using a JSP, the solution for me was to check inside the JSP being called to the Fancybox. There was an error in the JS in that JSP.